# What is the thrust to weight ratio of the A330-900neo?

Tags: commercial-aviation, thrust, airbus-a330

Does anyone know what the thrust-to-weight ratio is for the Airbus A330-900neo?

I'm getting different numbers when I try to calculate this for myself.

Comment: Maybe tell us what numbers you have, where you found them and how you’re calculating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thrust-to-weight ratio is not a single number because both thrust and weight vary throughout a flight:

> The thrust-to-weight ratio varies continually during a flight. Thrust varies with throttle setting, airspeed, altitude and air temperature. Weight varies with fuel burn and payload changes. For aircraft, the quoted thrust-to-weight ratio is often the maximum static thrust at sea level divided by the maximum takeoff weight.

<sup>([Wikipedia: Thrust-to-weight ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrust-to-weight_ratio))</sup>

For standard sea level conditions with maximum takeoff thrust and at maximum takeoff weight, we would get the following numbers ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A330neo#Specifications)) for the A330-900:

| Thrust / Engine | Total Thrust | Mass | Weight | Thrust-to-weight ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 324 kN | 648 kN | 251 t | 2462 kN | 0.263 |